# Memory efficiency :Passing Html code of aspx page through codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, streamreader

My goal is to generate the aspx code of a page in the form of string.I am calling the below codebehind code through asynchronous request in javascript and i am getting the response back through Response.Write

```
        string html = string.Empty;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
            {
                var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(streamWriter);
                base.Render(htmlWriter);
                htmlWriter.Flush();
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
                {
                    html = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    streamReader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        Response.Write(html);
        Response.End();
```

I want to ask that is the above code is memory efficient, I am thinking of "yield" to use as it evaluates lazily.Can u suggest on memory efficency of above code.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood correctly; do you want to return HTML rendered content for your page as a string? Can I ask why (maybe there's a simpler way)?

Comment: You can think of my case as there are two pages one.aspx and two.aspx i am calling the codebehind code of two.aspx page from one.aspx through javascript and when this two.aspx code behind code is called it will return its aspx code in the form of string to one.aspx page in the form of string

Comment: I'm still puzzled by the intent of this usage scenario. Interesting though.

Comment: @o.k.w my scenario is that i have to generate the html code in two.aspx on one.aspx in a div you can say ,i am calling the two.aspx.cs asynchronously and sending the html code of two.aspx.cs two one.aspx and append the html in div tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a StringWriter instead of the MemoryStream, the StreamWriter and the StreamReader:

```
string html;
using (StringWriter stream = new StringWriter()) {
   using (HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stream)) {
      base.Render(writer);
   }
   html = stream.ToString();
}
Response.Write(html);
Response.End();
```

The StringWriter uses a StringBuilder internally. The ToString method calls ToString on the Stringuilder, so it returns the internal string buffer as the string. That means that the string is only created once, and not copied back and forth.

Comment: This code is disposing stream twice, take a look at FxCop rule CA2202

Answer (score 1):

Your method stores an html copy at `html` variable, and another at `memoryStream`. Try this:

```
base.Render(new HtmlTextWriter(Response.Output));
Response.End();
```

While this can work, I'm not sure what are you trying to accomplish.